# disable http/2 requests in old react-native 0.38.1

Tags: react-native, http2

We have upgraded our Nginx server and some requests from a mobile app build with react native 0.38.1 http requests stoped working. If we disable http/2 on nginx the requests works again. The problem is noticed only on android phones.

Is there a way to disable react native http2 calls?

We use **RNFetchBlob.fetch(.... )** to execute http calls

the error we receive is

```
Error: Expected ':status' header not present
```